# Custom function to accept values for diamond operators

Tags: java

I have seen this in C#:

```
this.addComponent<MyClass>();
```

How would I make the method that use something like that? I tried doing this:

```
public Component addComponent<T>(){
    return new Component();
}
```

But it didn't work. Is it even possible to make something like that?

Comment: This works in C# because C# has reified generics (i.e. you can find out at run time what the generic type parameter was).  You can't do this in Java because Java ignores the type parameter at run time, and only uses it for type checking at compile time.  Consider passing a `Class` object as an argument to your method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking about [generic methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html), although I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do.

```
public <T extends Component> T addComponent(Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

The `<T extends Component>` before the return type (`T`) is what makes this a generic method. It enables you to pass an instance of any class that extends `Component` in as a parameter, and will return an object of the same type.

Couple of notes: First, the `Component` bound is optional:

```
public <T> T addComponent(Class<T> clazz){
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

would allow you to pass in any Class object and get back an of object of the same type.

Second, note that if you wanted to pass an instance in as a parameter rather than a `Class` object (which is a more typical use case), its type is inferred automatically:

```
public <T> T doStuff(T input){
    input.doStuff(); // does stuff to T instance
    return input; //return value is of type T
}
```

Finally, note that because of [type erasure](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html&ei=pAOdU7i4BsScyASUnIGgDg&usg=AFQjCNEBnOVe2r3hRwjUknNy696Du68q-Q&sig2=3M0lK8erZgBVXYkVXiDEkA&bvm=bv.68911936,d.aWw) you *cannot* instantiate or otherwise refer directly to the type of `T` in your method. For instance:

```
public <T extends Component> T doStuff(T input){
    T t = new T(); // NO! 
    T.someStaticMethod(); // NO! 
    return (T) new Component(); //hacky, but OK
}
```

(Also, I'm assuming you know that `Class.newInstance()` throws `InstantiationException`, although that's not reflected in above code)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this a little latter!

Comment: So to call the above it would be `this.addComponent(TestComp.class)` right?

Comment: Okay thanks! I wish it looked like the C# way, it looks cleaner IMO. Oh well, it seems to be doing what I want though!